# Effectively generating the folder path with backslashes

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to send the folder path to MySQL. So I have escaped each backslash. The path to be sent via javascript will be :

```
\\\\192.168.0.1\\foo\\bar
```

This will ultimately be saved as `(in db)`:

```
\\192.168.0.1\foo\bar
```

So, I wrote the following code:

```
        fpath = fpath.replace(/\\+/g,'\\\\'); // Replace multiple occurences of backslash with double backslash

        var fpathLen = fpath.length;

        if(fpath.charAt(fpathLen-1) == '\\')
            fpath = fpath.substring(0,fpathLen-2); // Remove the trailing backslash if any

        if(fpath.charAt(0) == '\\') {
            fpath = '\\\\' + fpath;  // Add 2 more backslash before sending the string to MySQL
        }
        else
            fpath = '\\\\\\\\' + fpath; // If string is without a leading backslash, insert 4 backslash
```

But it doesn't seem to be an effective way of doing things! For example, I have manually added `4`, in another case `8` backslashes to make it `2` and `4` respectively on `js` side. Is there a better way of achieving this?

Edit:
For an input path like `fpath = \\1.1.1.1\\\\\\\\foo\bar\\\config` , output should be `\\\\192.168.0.1\\foo\\bar`

Comment: Is requirement to replace `\\\\192.168.0.1\\foo\\bar` with `\\192.168.0.1\foo\bar` ?

Comment: @guest271314 No. For an input path like : `\\192.168.0.1\foo\bar\`  needs to be converted to `\\\\192.168.0.1\\foo\\bar`

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

You can do this by two regex:

```
fpath = fpath.replace(/\\+/g,'\\\\');
```

and

```
fpath = fpath.replace(/^\\*(.*?)\\*$/,'\\\\\\\\$1');
```

Demo:

```js
function makeFpath() {
  fpath = document.getElementById("fpath").value
  fpath = fpath.replace(/\\+/g, '\\\\').replace(/^\\*(.*?)\\*$/, '\\\\\\\\$1');

  document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = fpath
}

makeFpath()
```

```html
<input id="fpath" onkeyup="makeFpath()" onchange="makeFpath()" value="\\\1.1.1.1\\\\\\\\foo\bar\\\config\" style="width: 100%" />
<div id="out"></div>
```

---

**OLD:**
I think you got a little messed up with all the escaping*, is this doing it for you? :

```
fpath = fpath.replace(/\\/g,'\\\\'); // replaces a single \ by one double \\
```

you don't anything else if I understood your problem correctly

Comment: What would happen if  `fpath = \\1.1.1.1\\\\\\\\foo\bar\\\config\`? I should handle this and it should become  `\\\\1.1.1.1\\foo\\bar\\config`

Comment: you didn't mention this in your questions :( please update it

Comment: Man, the question wasn't obvious. But I think, the answer is now the one you wanted